# Image load store equivalent in OpenGL 3

Tags: opengl, glsl

My project should greatly benefit from arbitrary/atomic read and write operations in a texture from glsl shaders. The Image load store extension is what I need. Only problem, my target platform does not support OpenGL 4.
Is there an extension for OGL 3 that achieves similar results? I mean, atomic read/write operations in a texture or shared buffer of some sort from fragment shaders.

Comment: OpenGL isn't have any build-in functions for loading images!

Comment: @Vallentin it's not really about loading images ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Image Load Store](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store) and, especially atomic operations are features that must be backed up by specific hardware capabilities, that are very similar to features used in compute shaders. Only some of the GL3 hardware can handle it and only in a limited way.

1. [Image Load Store](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store)  in core profile since 4.2, so if your hardware (and driver) is capable of OpenGL 4.2, then you don't need any extensions at all
2. if your hardware (and driver) capabilities is lower than GL 4.2, but higher than GL 3.0,  you can, **probably**, use [`ARB_shader_image_load_store`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_image_load_store.txt) extension.

   - quote: `OpenGL 3.0 and GLSL 1.30 are required`
   - obviously, not all 3.0 hardware (and drivers) will support this extension, so *you must check for its support before use it*
   - I believe, most NVIDIA GL 3.3 hardware supports it, but not AMD or Intel (that's my subjective observations ;) ).
3. If your hardware is lower than GL 4.2 and not capable of this extension, nothing really you can do. Just have an alternative code path with texture sampling and rendering to texture and no atomics (as I understood this is possible, but without "great benefit of atomic"), or simply report an error to those users, who not yet upgraded their rigs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Very good answer. I believe my case is the last one. One of the testing machines has an nvidia 9600GT (OGL 3.3) and GLEW returned: `GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store: MISSING` So, yeah, looks like I need to rewrite my codes...